# chown directory in bash

Tags: bash, centos7

I am trying to chown a home directory test for an bash script. I need this functionality because of syncthing which is not syncing the ownerships.

```
#!/bin/bash

user=test

"chown $user:$user /home/$user"
```

When I use the above script, I get a message "test.sh: line 5: chown test:test ~/home/test/: No such file or directory
"

Output of

```
ls -l /home/ |grep test
drwx------   5 pwresettest     1005  121  2. Nov 04:23 pwresettest
drwx------  14 test            1001 4096 29. Okt 05:41 test
```

When I am using the command on the commandline, it works without problems.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: When you use `chown` on the command line you aren't quoting the entire command. Don't do that in the script either.

Comment: worked .. it seems like i just posted the wrong topic. chown did not work because of another command

Answer (score 3):

The shell treats the quoted string as a single word to as the name of the command, rather than a command name followed by arguments. Simply take off the quotes you've added in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=test

chown $user:$user /home/$user
```

Comment: The solution here is correct but the first part of the description of the problem makes no sense at all.

Comment: Etan, Thanks for clarifying that for me!

Answer (score -2):

When you use chown on the command line you aren't quoting the entire command. Don't do that in the script either. – Etan Reisner