# How to set permissions in Linux on files?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

I have directory `upload` in Linux system.

How to set permission root:root on all files are cretaed inside this directory?
By default is `apache [48]: apache [48]`, but I need `root:root`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chown diretory in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480688/chown-diretory-in-bash)

Comment: Are you really sure you need root:root? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `chown` man page:
-R, --recursive
   operate on files and directories recursively

`chown -R root:root upload`

Comment: All directories and files have root permissions, but when I upload file via FTP in PHP it creates directory `/system/storage/upload/tmp` with `apache [48] : apache [48]` permissions. Why?

Comment: Because your php is running under web server apache. Apache use `apache` user to run web server. That's why your files is creating under apache user.

Comment: Okay, then how can I fix this and set up setting to Apache?

Comment: Run apache server under root user. But this is very bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

The above one works also try the below one.

chown -R root: upload

## Group name takes automatically